# Finding top 5 results for multiple values in sql result

Tags: mysql

I have the following sql query:

```
SELECT v.venue_id, s.zip, COUNT( * ) 
FROM bcs_scans s
JOIN bcs_scanners sc ON s.uuid = sc.uuid
JOIN bcs_venues v ON sc.venue_id = v.venue_id
WHERE v.banlist_id =  '625'
AND s.del =0
GROUP BY s.zip
ORDER BY COUNT( * ) DESC
```

Which returns the count of individual zip codes, their count, and associated venue.

[image: zip results]

How do I go about selecting the top 5 zip codes for each unique venue id?

I believe I can run a subquery that groups results by venue id with the top 5 zip counts, but I am unsure of where to start

Answer (score 0):

Could be you select the result in this way ... a bit complex ..

using the having for extract the value that match the max count group by venue_id   from your original query ..

```
    SELECT v.venue_id as  venue_id, s.zip as , COUNT( * ) as num
    FROM bcs_scans s
    JOIN bcs_scanners sc ON s.uuid = sc.uuid
    JOIN bcs_venues v ON sc.venue_id = v.venue_id
    WHERE v.banlist_id =  '625'
    AND s.del =0
    GROUP BY s.zip
    HAVING ( v.venue_id, COUNT( * )) in 
    (select  venue_id, max(num)
    from 
    (SELECT v.venue_id as  venue_id, s.zip as , COUNT( * ) as num
    FROM bcs_scans s
    JOIN bcs_scanners sc ON s.uuid = sc.uuid
    JOIN bcs_venues v ON sc.venue_id = v.venue_id
    WHERE v.banlist_id =  '625'
    AND s.del =0
    GROUP BY s.zip
    ORDER BY COUNT( * ) DESC ) a t 
    group by venue_id) 
    ORDER BY COUNT( * ) limit 5
```